# How would I parse/split this custom string into an array?

Tags: php, string

Thanks in advance for any assistance you could offer.

I have a string like this:

```
[{"title":"Image One","description":"Image One\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"111"}},{"title":"Image Two","description":"Image Two Description","image":{"attachment_id":"222"}},{"title":"Image Three","description":"Image Three\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"333"}}]
```

I am not sure how I could put it into an array so that I could utilise all of the Attachment ID's?

Something like:

```
echo $attachment_id[0];
echo $attachment_id[1];
```

etc.

Comment: in this post answer maximum answered json_decode(). I also used this. so why my answer is downvoted , i don't understand.If anybody explain that will be thankful for me. thanks. now I get it why it's downvoted. no need to reply. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "string" you have is in JSON format, PHP has some functions built in to use it!

You can either turn it into an object or an array with [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

Here's an example to turn it into a PHP array:

```
<?php

    $json = '[{"title":"Image One","description":"Image One\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"111"}},{"title":"Image Two","description":"Image Two Description","image":{"attachment_id":"222"}},{"title":"Image Three","description":"Image Three\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"333"}}]';
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($data);
```

The output of which is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Image One
            [description] => Image One
Description
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [attachment_id] => 111
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Image Two
            [description] => Image Two Description
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [attachment_id] => 222
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Image Three
            [description] => Image Three
Description
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [attachment_id] => 333
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is JSON.

PHP has a built in [JSON parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) you can use:

```
$attachments = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($attachments as $att) {
    echo $att["title"] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$encoded-variable = [{"title":"Image One","description":"Image One\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"111"}},{"title":"Image Two","description":"Image Two Description","image":{"attachment_id":"222"}},{"title":"Image Three","description":"Image Three\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"333"}}]`

```
 use     `$result = json_decode($encoded_varaible,true);'
```

Comment: I spy with my little eye, something beginning with: parse error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a string. Put it in quotes, then it is a string, more precisely it is [JSON](http://www.json.org/) . You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it into an array.

```
$myString = '[{"title":"Image One","description":"Image One\r\nDescription","image":
   {"attachment_id":"111"}},{"title":"Image Two","description":"Image Two 
   Description","image":{"attachment_id":"222"}},{"title":"Image 
   Three","description":"Image Three\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"333"}}]';

$myArray = json_decode($myString, true);
var_dump($myArray[0]['image']['attachment_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a JSON encoded string. Just decode it into and array with json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php and get what you need.

```
<?php
$string = 'the string above';

$array = json_decode($string, true);
$attachments = array_map(function($e) {
    return $e['image']['attachment_id']; 
}, $array);
print_r($attachments); // prints Array (114, 222, 333)
```

Answer (score -1):

use  json_decode() like below. you will get an array in result.
`json_decode([{"title":"Image One","description":"Image One\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"111"}},{"title":"Image Two","description":"Image Two Description","image":{"attachment_id":"222"}},{"title":"Image Three","description":"Image Three\r\nDescription","image":{"attachment_id":"333"}}])`

Comment: You'd actually get a parse error. Even if it worked it would be an object, not an array.